# How do I target a link to update an <iframe> on the same page, instead of to a new url/page?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Right now, when you click a button in my table, it takes you to a new page that prints out data from the associated record/table row on a new page. The table row with the button looks like this:

```
echo '<input type="button" value="Offer" 
onclick="window.location=\'more_info.php?start=' . urlencode($row['Title']) . ' \';" />';
```

And this is the associated php file:

```
<?php

  $start = (!empty($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start'] : false);
  echo '<h1>Offer to sell: ' . $start . '</h1>';

?>
```

What I want to do, instead of having the information print on a new page, is target it to an 'iframe' below the table, on the same page. Or any other way of displaying more data associated with the table record being clicked, below the table (not expanding the cell).

Anyone know how to go about this?

Comment: Why use an iframe? Use AJAX and update the content of a `div` element.

Comment: @Geoffrey Ok, interesting -  I don't know any AJAX, but will look into that.

Comment: I suggest you look at JQuery, it has a very nice AJAX api.

Comment: also, don't use echo like this: you're string concatenating arbitrary data without even verifying that what's in the variables you use is safe. That's an incredibly dangerous thing to do. Learn a bit about using javascript to ask your PHP server for some data, learn a bit about making PHP return JSON objects when calling special URLs, and then combine those two so that your website is responsible for the "once it's loaded in the browser" parts. Need to update a part of the page? Make JavaScript ask your server for some data, and then have JS update the page. No PHP other than data serving.

Comment: @Mike Ok, will do - thanks for the advice. Just getting started.

Comment: There's a ton of good tutorials out there, it's worth googling for a few and then following *a few* rather than just one, because if you're just starting, you deserve getting multiple teachers. And if the tutorial teaches you to write PHP peppered with fragments that you `echo`, with string concaternation on the PHP side, or it advocates using `document.write` on the JavaScript side: close that tutorial and move on to a more modern one. Terms you want to google for: "php javascript full stack tutorial" will get you started.

Comment: Thanks - I am at a point where I am just satisfied to have made something that functions on a basic level, but the security issue is the big question mark for me, if I ever want to publish what I am making. So this info is very helpful to me, thank you.